# Recursive function that adds to json array

Tags: php, json, recursion

I have the following function:

```
function getJsonStuff($page_id, $token = "")
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/id=" . $page_id . "&pageToken=" . $token), true);

    if (isset($json["token"]) && !empty($json["token"]))
    {
        getJsonStuff($playlist_id, $json["token"]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $json;
    }
}
```

The JSON given on the page I'm retrieving it from only returns 20 results, but gives a pagination token for the next 20 results.

The recursive function is meant to go through all of the JSON results until there is no next page token given.

How do I add the JSON results from each page into a single variable, so that I have a variable with all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach a solution to this by using a while loop rather than recursion:

```
function getJsonStuff($page_id) {
    $url = "https://www.example.com/id=" . $page_id . "&pageToken=";
    $results = array();
    $token = "";

    while(true) {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $token), true);

        if (!isset($json["token"]) || empty($json["token"])) {
            break;
        }

        $token = $json["token"];
        $results[] = $json;
    }

    return $results;
}
```